# Are Postscript expressions allowed in pscircle's radius?

Tags: pstricks

I am using PSTricks and I'm trying to draw a circle whose radius is computed as a Postscript expression. This is a simplified, minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot, auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\def\side{2}
\def\radius{\side\space .5 sub}
\pscircle(! 2 1){\radius}
\pscircle(! 2 1){1.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

While the “pscircle” with radius literally 1.5 is drawn correctly, the one with the predefined radius “\radius” (which should simply be equal to 2 - .5) generates a small circle and the character string “.5 sub”.

What am I doing wrong? Is the radius in braces parsed differently from other graphic parameters, and so it doesn't accept my Postscript expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using Postscript code in the centre coordinates of the circles, indicated by a `!` at the beginning. The same needs to be done with the radius as well:

```
\pscircle(! 2 1){!\radius}
```

Besides, pkg `auto-pst-pdf` is not needed anymore, since it is possible to directly typeset to PDF with `lualatex`, thanks to Marcel Krueger's [Postscript interpreter](https://ctan.org/pkg/luapstricks) written in Lua:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\def\side{2}
\def\radius{\side\space .5 sub}
\pscircle(! 2 1){!\radius}
\pscircle(! 2 1){1.5}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, of course! For some reason, I associated the ! to point coordinates, but of course it is needed wherever PS code is used. Thanks!

Comment: but `\pscircle(! 2 1)`  makes no real sense, it is identical to `\pscircle(2,1)`